# How to use scp to copy to VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, scp

My mininet virtual box

```
hostname
mininet-vm
```

`ip a` shows

```
inet 10.0.2.15/24
```

From my client, transferring to the remote VM:

```
scp 6jan.txt mininet-vm@10.0.2.15
```

I can not see any transferred files.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a colon at the end.

It's not

> scp 6jan.txt mininet-vm@10.0.2.15

but

> scp 6jan.txt mininet-vm@10.0.2.15:

You will see that you have a new local file, now called:

> mininet-vm@10.0.2.15